# Downloading Cocoapods

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods on my intel mac. But I keep getting error. I run `sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose`. At first when it starts to download it shows ->

```
HEAD https://rubygems.org/api/v1/dependencies
404 Not Found
```

All others are 200 OK. And at the end I get

```
Error installing cocoapods:
    The last version of activesupport (>= 5.0, < 8) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 6.1.7.6. Try installing it with `gem install activesupport -v 6.1.7.6` and then running the current command again
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

I tried what it says but it did not solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hey you'll need to update gem

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Comment: I get an error -> ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
 There are no versions of rubygems-update (= 3.5.1) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
 rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the lastest verion of Ruby. with `rvm install 3.2.2` (Despite I face with an error while compiling process). Then I tried sudo gem install cocoapods --verbose. And It worked.(I dont have an idea how it worked lol)